# How to only allow a popup message to occur on first visit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm working to include a GDPR-style / Cookie notification for when users visit our site for the first time, but not again until they clear their cache. I have a notification set up to show when the window opens, and a close button to close it.

I've tried using localStorage and sessionStorage jquery, similar to those used to help other users, including hiding the popup first then checking in localStorage to see if it's there:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#toast').hide();
        var element= localStorage.getItem('status');
        if (element == null || element == '') {
            localStorage.setItem('element', 1);
            $('#toast').show();
        }});
```

But 1) I don't want to copy pasta because 2) it doesn't work.

html for the popup here:

```
<div id="toast" class="toast-close fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #DB7232; color: white; opacity: .7; margin: 0 0 2rem 2rem; padding: 1rem; width: 18rem;">
     <small>By continuing to browse this site, you're accepting the use of cookies.</small>
     <small><button type="button" data-dismiss="toast" class="close" aria-label="Close">&times</button></small>
</div>
```

the jquery to close the popup here:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.toast-close', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
           $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

I expect when a user comes to our site for the first time (or since we add this feature) the popup will occur; once they x out of either the popup or the browser, the notification will not occur again until their cache is cleared.

Comment: Presumably you do this _prior_ to setting cookie(s). If they accept, then you've stored the cookie(s). So on each visit - pseudo code: `if( cookie is set) then do not show popup!` Where is the flaw in this idea?

Comment: Not everyone specifically asks for consent.   This "by continuing to browse the site" meets the legal bar even if it is an unusual experience.  However, that doesn't really change the solution... it just treats any other page action as registering consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading 'status', but setting 'element'. Those two names should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The part that you believe you are missing I am unsure of.

Your general code flow:
1) Check for cookie/localstorage
2) Conditionally render popup
3) Set cookie/localstorage if user Consents

I see you have a .hide() before your cookie logic.   I'd keep that html fragment somewhere else (display:none?) unless you specifically need it.

It seems like you know how to display/fade it in if you need it.